# Ubuntu connecting to two wifi adapters(only want one)

Tags: networking, network-manager

SO I'm having a few problems, I'll start off by saying I just recently made the switch to Ubuntu from Windows. I have two wifi adapters, one is my built in NIC and the other is an external adapter. I use the external adapter because my internal adapter is faulty and gives off a very weak signal. The problem is I'm getting two connections, well Ubuntu is telling me I am connected to both the external card and internal card simultaneously. My connection seems to be also dropping every couple of minutes and I have to plug out my external card an reconnect in order to regain connectivity. Is there a way to disable one of the adapters(Ideally through the terminal)

here is the output of iwconfig

```
iwconfig 
*lo        no wireless extensions.
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VM172"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 90:5C:44:28:48:C1   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=17/70  Signal level=-93 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:18   Missed beacon:0

wlxe84e0658eb90  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VM172"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 90:5C:44:28:48:C1   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:79   Missed beacon:0
tun0      no wireless extensions.*
```

*edit I'm trying to format it a little better, sorry about format. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64 bit machine.

Thanks chili555 here is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e09a]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that we blacklist the driver for the internal device. In order to determine what the driver is, please run the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Chilli, just updated the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you unload and blacklist the driver for the internal device. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r ath10k_pci
echo "blacklist ath10k_pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You also may have fewer drops with:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Thanks Chilli, the first command solved the issue of connecting to the internal NIC card :)

as far as fewer drops, I'll report back in about an hour with results. Thanks

Comment: after 3 hours, connection doesn't seem to be dropping anymore :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected.